# How do I zip, merge or concat using rxSwift without overriding previous data?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, concatenation, rx-swift

I have three `Observable<[Recipe]>` streams that I want to combine into one single `Observable<[Recipe]>`.

```
let breakfast = Database.database().reference().rx.fetchFireBaseData(recipeType: .breakfast)
    .map { $0.filter { UserDefaults.standard.favoriteRecipes.contains($0.fbKey) }}
        
let dessert = Database.database().reference().rx.fetchFireBaseData(recipeType: .dessert)
    .map { $0.filter { UserDefaults.standard.favoriteRecipes.contains($0.fbKey) }}

let cookies = Database.database().reference().rx.fetchFireBaseData(recipeType: .cookies)
    .map { $0.filter { UserDefaults.standard.favoriteRecipes.contains($0.fbKey) }}
```

If I use `Observable.zip(breakfast, dessert, cookies).do(onNext: { [weak self] value in...`
I get `([Recipe], [Recipe], [Recipe])`

If I use `Observable.merge(breakfast, dessert, cookies).do(onNext: { [weak self] value in...`
I get the streams in turns, meaning that the last one completed overrides the previous two.

If I use `Observable.concat(breakfast, dessert, cookies).do(onNext: { [weak self] value in...`
I get sort of the same behavior as with `merge`.

So how do I combine the three streams into one without having them overwriting one another?

To get a better idea what I'm trying to do:

```
return Observable.merge(breakfast, cookies, dessert).do(onNext: { [weak self] value in
    self?.content.accept(value.compactMap { FavoritesCollectionViewCellViewModel(favorite: $0)})
})
```

I want to `accept` all combined streams to the `behaviorRelay`, mapped to `cell` data. The `content` relay is then `bound` to a `collectionView`. When watching the `collectionView`, with `concat` I can see first and second stream briefly, then they are replaced with the last stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not know, but combineLatest (and zip) has a final parameter for manipulating the inputs. So you could do something like:

```
let allRecipes = Observable.combineLatest(breakfast, dessert, cookies) { $0 + $1 + $2 }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
Observable.combineLatest(breakfast, dessert, cookies)
        .map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 }
```

Which is essentially the same as what you ended up with, except you used `zip` instead of `combineLatest`

Using `zip` assumes that all three Observables will emit exactly the same number of elements. By using combineLatest, you assume that each Observable emits at least one element, but they don't have to all emit the same number.

If you wanted to avoid even that assumption, then add a `.startWith` to each source.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    breakfast.startWith([]),
    dessert.startWith([]),
    cookies.startWith([])
) { $0 + $1 + $2 }
```

With the above, as soon as any one source observable emits, you will get something in your output, and another, larger, array each time the others emit.

Note that in all of the above (including your answer) an error in any one of the source observables will cause the entire thing to error out. If you want to avoid that, you will have to catch the errors at each source Observable. Exactly what that code looks like depends on what you want to do with the errors.

Comment: That's a really nice explanation, many thanks @Daniel T.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't know if this is the prettiest way to solve it, but I used `zip` then just added the arrays to one another in `compactMap`

```
return Observable.zip(breakfast, dessert, cookies)
    .compactMap { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 }
    .do(onNext: { [weak self] value in
        self?.content.accept(value.compactMap { FavoritesCollectionViewCellViewModel(favorite: $0)})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in my case you can see the difference between using combineLatest with .map and just opened closures.

Going through this way

```
Observable.combineLatest(breakfast, dessert, cookies)
        .map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 }
```

gives you much faster compiling and work then escaping .map like this

```
Observable.combineLatest(breakfast, dessert, cookies) { $0 + $1 + $2 }
```

Just in my example I share with you some screenshots with sequence combined requests:

[compile in about 0.3s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ctvH.png)

```
    func countries() -> Observable<[University]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(getCountry(with: "Poland"), getCountry(with: "Belarus"), getCountry(with: "Ukraine"), getCountry(with: "Estonia"), getCountry(with: "Latvia")).map { $0.0 + $0.1 + $0.2 + $0.3 + $0.4 }
}
```

[second case. difference in about 70x !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7W4V.png)

```
    func countries() -> Observable<[University]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(getCountry(with: "Poland"), getCountry(with: "Belarus"), getCountry(with: "Ukraine"), getCountry(with: "Estonia"), getCountry(with: "Latvia")) { $0 + $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! But aren't they the same? I assumed that only using {} is the same as .map {}, but some sort of shorthand or implicit use of .map{}. Why is .map{}  much faster?